# Can't fetch cognitive service token in webchat

Tags: javascript, azure, botframework, access-token, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to convert Mock-Bot from MS botframework samples (https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.c.cognitive-services-speech-services-js) to use my own Cognitive Services resource. I tried changing region in endpoint but it didn't help me. For the code below I get this error: GET https://westus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/voices/list net::ERR_ABORTED 401.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Web Chat: Cognitive Services Speech Services using JavaScript</title>
    <!-- Cognitive Services Speech Services adapter is only available in full bundle -->

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!--
      This CDN points to the latest official release of Web Chat. If you need to test against Web Chat's latest bits, please refer to pointing to Web Chat's MyGet feed:
      https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#how-to-test-with-web-chats-latest-bits
    -->
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
      }
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }

      #webchat {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script>
      // Create a function to fetch the Cognitive Services Speech Services credentials.
      // The async function created will hold expiration information about the token and will return cached token when possible.
      function createFetchSpeechServicesCredentials() {
        let expireAfter = 0;
        let lastResult = {};

        return async () => {
          // Fetch a new token if the existing one is expiring.
          // The following article mentioned the token is only valid for 10 minutes.
          // We will invalidate the token after 5 minutes.
          // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/authentication#authenticate-with-an-authentication-token
          if (Date.now() > expireAfter) {

            const speechServicesTokenRes = await fetch(
              'https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken',
              { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'MyCognitiveServicesSubscriptionKey' } }
            );      
/*
            const speechServicesTokenRes = await fetch(
              'https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/speechservices/token',
              { method: 'POST' }
            );         
*/
            lastResult = await speechServicesTokenRes;//.json();
            expireAfter = Date.now() + 300000;
          }

          return lastResult;
        };
      }

      const fetchSpeechServicesCredentials = createFetchSpeechServicesCredentials();

      async function fetchSpeechServicesRegion() {
        return (await fetchSpeechServicesCredentials()).region;
      }

      async function fetchSpeechServicesToken() {
        return (await fetchSpeechServicesCredentials()).token;
      }

      (async function() {
        // In this demo, we are using Direct Line token from MockBot.
        // Your client code must provide either a secret or a token to talk to your bot.
        // Tokens are more secure. To learn about the differences between secrets and tokens.
        // and to understand the risks associated with using secrets, visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

        const res = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', { method: 'POST', headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer MySecret' }});
        const { token } = await res.json();

        // Create the ponyfill factory function, which can be called to create a concrete implementation of the ponyfill.
        const webSpeechPonyfillFactory = await window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({
          // We are passing the Promise function to the authorizationToken field.
          // This function will be called every time the token is being used.
          authorizationToken: fetchSpeechServicesToken,

          // In contrast, we are only fetching the region once.
          //region: await fetchSpeechServicesRegion()
        });


        const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
          if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
            // When we receive DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED action, we will send an event activity using WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT
            dispatch({
              type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
              payload: {
                name: 'webchat/join',
                value: { language: window.navigator.language }
              }
            });
          }
          return next(action);
        });

        // Pass a Web Speech ponyfill factory to renderWebChat.
        // You can also use your own speech engine given it is compliant to W3C Web Speech API: https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/.
        // For implementor, look at createBrowserWebSpeechPonyfill.js for details.
        window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
          {
            directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
            webSpeechPonyfillFactory,
            locale: 'en-US',
            store
          },
          document.getElementById('webchat')
        );

        document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
      })().catch(err => console.error(err));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help.

Edit: Apparently the error is SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain why the above produces an error, however if I simplify it the error disappears. Try this which worked for me:

```js
let authorizationToken;
let region;
const speechServicesTokenRes = await fetch(
  'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken',
  { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'MyCognitiveServicesSubscriptionKey' } }
);

if (speechServicesTokenRes.status === 200) {
  region = 'westeurope',
  authorizationToken = await speechServicesTokenRes.text()
} else {
  return (new Error('error!'))
}

const webSpeechPonyfillFactory = await window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory( {
  authorizationToken: authorizationToken,
  region: region
} );

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
  directLine: directLine,
  webSpeechPonyfillFactory: webSpeechPonyfillFactory
}, document.getElementById('webchat') );
```

Hope of help!

Answer (score 0):

In the code you need to define *credentials* object with authorizationToken and region properties and pass the object to '*createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory*' method.

Sample code:

```
<div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
<script>
  (async function() {
    let authorizationToken;
    let region;
    const speechServicesTokenRes = await fetch(
      'https://<your-speech-service-region-eg-uksouth>.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '<your-speech-api-key>'
        }
      }
    );

    if (speechServicesTokenRes.status === 200) {
      region = '<your-azure-region-eg-uksouth>',
        authorizationToken = await speechServicesTokenRes.text()
    } else {
      return (new Error('error!'))
    }

    const webSpeechPonyfillFactory = await window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({
      credentials: {
        authorizationToken: authorizationToken,
        region: region
      }
    });

    var dl = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
      secret: '<your-directline-default-site-secret>'
    });

    window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
      directLine: dl,
      webSpeechPonyfillFactory: webSpeechPonyfillFactory
    }, document.getElementById('webchat'));

  })().catch(err => console.error(err));

</script>
```

Hope this helps!